# Dynamically referencing a variable in jinja2?

Tags: jinja2

Is it possible to dynamically reference a variable in jinja2?

```
{%- set varA = 5 -%}
{%- set varB = 10 -%}
{%- set input = 'A' -%}

{%- set output = 'var' + input -%}
Output: {{ output }}

{# I get "Output: varA", but I would like to get "Output: 5" #}
```

I can do it with an `if/else` statement, but want to see if i can do it dynamically, in case i have inputs `A-Z`, for example.

```
{%- if input == 'A' -%}
  {%- set output = varA -%}
{%- else -%}
  {%- set output = varB -%}
{%- endif -%}
Output: {{ output }}
```

I thought a macro might help, but seems to return as a string:

```
{%- macro doit(input) -%}
  var{{input}}
{%- endmacro -%}

{%- set output = doit(input) -%}
Output: {{ output }}
{# Returns "Output: varA" #}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try that:

```
template = """
    {%- set varA = 5 -%}
    {%- set input = 'A' -%}
    {%- set output = 'var' ~ input  -%}
    Output: {{ self._TemplateReference__context.resolve(output) }}
"""
temp = jinja2.Template(template)
result = temp.render()
print(result)
```

result:

```
Output: 5
```